# Need to shift the data to next column, unfortunately added data in wrong column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `test`

```
+----+--+------+--+--+--------------+--+--------------+
| ID |  | Name1    |  |  |  Name2     |  
+----+--+------+--+--+--------------+--+--------------+
|  1 |  | Andy     |  |  |   NULL     |  
|  2 |  | Kevin    |  |  |   NULL     |  
|  3 |  | Phil     |  |  |   NULL     |  
|  4 |  | Maria    |  |  |   NULL     |  
|  5 |  | Jackson  |  |  |   NULL     |  
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--+--
```

I am expecting output like

```
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--
| ID |  | Name1 |  |  | Name2   |  
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--
|  1 |  | NULL  |  |  | Andy    |  
|  2 |  | NULL  |  |  | Kevin   |  
|  3 |  | NULL  |  |  | Phil    |  
|  4 |  | NULL  |  |  | Maria   |  
|  5 |  | NULL  |  |  | Jackson |  
+----+--+------+--+--+----------+--
```

I unfortunately inserted data in wrong column and now I want to shift the data to the next column.

Comment: is everything null in name2 column?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement with no `WHERE` condition, to cover the entire table.

```
UPDATE test
SET Name2 = Name1,
    Name1 = NULL
```

Comment: Just curious, if name2 had values, can those we swapped in one go?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh yes, because the new values are only stored once all "assignments" are complete

Comment: @Lucero - I just tried it. It works in SQL Server and oracle, but not in MySQL.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh because MySQL does not follow the SQL standard, as noted in the docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html